# Netplan with 2 NICs each connected to a different gateway

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking

Anyone familiar enough with Netplan?

I'm a bit confused on how to configure an Ubuntu 18 server with two NICS using Netplan. Each NIC is on a separate subnet. They are directly connected to separate router interfaces on the router (this is a SMB router so each interface is configured as a different subnet).

So for example on the server I have two NICs named below with the appropriate information they need:

eth0 - 192.168.2.2/24
       gateway - 192.168.2.1
       dns - 192.168.2.1

eth1 - 192.168.22.2/24
       gateway - 192.168.22.1
       dns - 192.168.22.1

I was playing around with the source routing example at netplan.io, but its not quite what I want. I don't want to route all outgoing traffic through just one interface. I need to be able to route traffic out of eth0 through eth0's gateway and I need to be able to route traffic out of eth1 through eth1's gateway.

I'll let the router handle routing between the two subnets via firewall rules. I just need Neplan to play nice with my two NICs and let me setup two subnets each with its own gateway information. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      addresses:
       - 192.168.2.2/24
      dhcp4: no
      routes:
       - to: 192.168.2.0/24
         via: 192.168.2.1
         table: 101
      routing-policy:
       - from: 192.168.2.0/24
         table: 101
    ens5:
      addresses:
       - 192.168.22.2/24
      dhcp4: no
      gateway4: 192.168.22.1
      routes:
       - to: 192.168.22.0/24
         via: 192.168.22.1
         table: 102
      routing-policy:
        - from: 192.168.22.0/24
          table: 102
```

#### Source routing

Route tables can be added to particular interfaces to allow routing between two networks:

In the example below, `ens3` is on the `192.168.2.0/24` network and `ens5` is on the `192.168.22.0/24` network. This enables clients on either network to connect to the other and allow the response to come from the correct interface.

Furthermore, the default route is still assigned to `ens5` allowing any other traffic to go through it.
Unfortunaly this is the most close way to use two gateways independent that I found I tried to add `gateway4` on `ens`3 and the firewall detect spoofing because for some reason the netplan will return the traffic the wrong way. tomorrow i'm going to rollback netplan to ifupdown in order to work with routing tables, etc. is more flexible.
Reference [here](https://netplan.io/examples)

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be approaching routing in the wrong way, you cannot have two default gateways , ok technically you can with different metrics  but that's for fail overs nit interface routing  . You have a ens3 and ens5 192.168.2.22 or 192.168.22.22 . Think of this like a default route is to state 0.0.0.0/0 goes via 192.168.2.1 as a gateway (route) you would need to be more specific such as route add 8.8.8.8/32 via ens5 so then google dns requests would go via that nic . If your getting spoofing warnings from the firewall then it could be for a few reasons , 1) your switch has port security turned on and is seeing a router on a stick (lots of vlan interfaces on the same mac address) 2) it may be detecting asymmetric routing as spoofing as only one half of traffic arrives . If your host has two nics eg 192.168.2.50 routing via 192.168.2.1 and another nic 192.168.22.50 routing via 192.168.22.1  anything that wants to connect to your host must have a reverse route to get back to the router ,( sometimes there is more than one firewall) the other reason maybe is that the switch your connected to is a virtual switch, which by default is the way vmware configured there switches , you would need promiscuous mode for the switch and nics your attached too .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, every NIC can have in every NIC a default gateway and work independently, but for that you must need an advance routing policy as follow:

https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure the interfaces dynamicaly `dhcp4: yes` by DHPC client:

```
# networks
network_1 ens3: 10.0.10.0/24
network_2 ens8: 10.0.20.0/24
 
# /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      dhcp4: yes
    ens8:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-routes: false
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.20.1
          table: 200
        - to: 10.0.20.0/24
          via: 10.0.20.1
          table: 200
      routing-policy:
        - from: 10.0.20.0/24
          table: 200
```